# Programming customized tab completion for zsh

Tags: zsh, tabs, completion, tab-completion

Sorry if my google fu is too weak, but: I simply want to adjust zsh so that I can tab complete

```
someappname -s
```

using the contents (filenames) of ~/somedir

For example:

```
someapp -s f<tab>
```

should cycle through completions based on the files starting with the letter f in ~/somedir .  So I might end up with a command line like: "someapp -s foobar".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I worked this out: ([source at github](http://github.com/Pistos/diakonos/blob/2a449b47cdf996d796989719abfa30f2564b4e44/_diakonos_zsh_completion))

```
#compdef diakonos

typeset -A opt_args
local context state line
local sessiondir
sessiondir=${HOME}/.diakonos/sessions

_arguments -n -s -S \
  "-s[specify session]:session:_files -W $sessiondir" \
  "*:file:_files" \
  && return 0

return 1
```

I referenced http://www.linux-mag.com/id/1106 ([free] registration required to read), and got help from #zsh on freenode.

Comment: You might also check out the book _From Bash to Z Shell_ by Oliver Kiddle, Jerry Peek and Peter Stephenson.

Answer (score 5):

A simpler approach:

```
compdef "_files -W ~/somedir -/" someappname
```

Comment: If `someappname` takes only directories as arguments, you can use `_directories` instead of `_files`.